# Auto Import data from One Table to another Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my requirement:

Table 1:

```
S.No   Item   Quantity   Warehouse      Date    
1       01      10         PA         02/06/2019
2       02      15         CA         02/06/2019
3       03      25         FI         02/06/2019
4       04      50         MI         03/06/2019
5       05      25         CA         03/06/2019
```

Table 2:

```
S.No   Item   Quantity  Warehouse
```

I want the information from Table 1 to import or insert into Table 2 at a specific time(For Example: 11 am)

Also I don't want the duplication of the data in table 2.

If the above information is updated or imported in Table 2, Is it possible to provide any kind of flag to the data that has been already imported in table 1.

I am new to SQL, So I don't know much about the DDL or DML.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or MySQL? They are 2 very different RDBMS. Can you please retag the appropriate DBMS, and only that one? What attempts have you made so far? Even if they failed, please do show us your efforts and explain why they didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: This has little to do with databases and a lot about scheduling jobs.

Comment: I haven't performed any steps now..Just create a query in order to capture information from Table1....It's MS SQL Server express edition. Table_1 is in One Database & Table2 is in another database...Both these database are in MS SQL Server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this will help.

Create a SQL Agent job that will be executing your SQL script on the schedule. (Read about SQL jobs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms189237(v=sql.110) or from other platform of your preference).

Once you get in scheduling the job, the query you will use to copy table1 to table2 is:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Table2 -- you may need to truncate it every time. Otherwise, use your way of managing duplicates. 
SELECT * INTO Table2 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I have MS SQL express edition...It doesn't support SQL agent job